# NiFi SplitJSON and ExecuteSQL

Tags: apache-nifi

In a NiFi flow, I want to read a JSON structure, split it, use the payload   to execute a SQL query, and finally output each result in a JSON file.

However I am having problems retrieving the value of the splitted FlowFile's attribute in the `ExecuteSQL` processor.

[image]

1. `GenerateFlowFile` processor, with a JSON structure as `Custom Text`

[image]

2. `SplitJSON`, with data as the attribute to be splitted

[image]

3. `ExecuteSQL`, with the query I am trying to execute, using the `SplitJSON's` payload attribute `${id}`

[image]

At this point I am getting a log error of a SQL syntax error. Apparently the `ExecuteQuery` processor is not parsing the expression on its `SQL select query` property.

Is there any intermediate processing left to be done after splitting the JSON? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an additional `EvaluateJsonPath` (or `ExtractText`) processor between `SplitJson` and `ExecuteSQL` -- the Expression Language expression cannot evaluate the flowfile content for parameter substitution, so your SQL expression ends up being `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ;` which is why you have a syntax error.

Expression Language reads from flowfile attributes, so you need to parse the JSON content into an accessible attribute. The `EvaluateJsonPath` processor does exactly this. All you need to do is add a custom property (click the `+` on the top right of the properties dialog) and extract the `id` value from the JSON into a flowfile attribute. Then connect the `matched` relationship from this processor to the `ExecuteSQL` processor.

[image: EvaluateJsonPath processor with custom property]

Comment: Ahh the missing link. Thank you for your time, that was it.